# Reading a binary number from a file and saving it as an integer

Tags: c, image, converters, ppm

I am trying to write a converter from P6 to P3, which means from data saved in binary to data saved in ASCII.

This is the function I wrote to do the job but `red`,`green` and `blue` integers get garbage values instead of their decimal value.

```
int convertP6toP3(char* fileName)
{
    FILE *src, *dest;
    char *outputFilename;
    char magicNumber[3];
    int height, width, depth;
    int red = 0, green = 0, blue = 0;
    int i, j, widthCounter = 1;

    if (checkFileExists(fileName) == FALSE)
    {
        printf("- Given file does not exists!\n");
        return ERROR;
    }

    else
        src = fopen(fileName, "rb");

    outputFilename = getOutputFilename(fileName, ".p3.ppm");
    dest = fopen(outputFilename, "w+");

    // check that the input file is actually in P6 format
    fscanf(src, "%s", magicNumber);
    if (strcmp(magicNumber, "P6") != 0)
        return ERROR;
    fscanf(src, "%d %d %d", &height, &width, &depth);

    fprintf(dest, "P3\n");
    fprintf(dest, "#P3 converted from P6\n");
    fprintf(dest, "%d %d\n%d\n", height, width, depth);

    for (i = 0; i < width*height; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            fread(&red, sizeof(int), 1, src);
            fread(&green, sizeof(int), 1, src);
            fread(&blue, sizeof(int), 1, src);
        }

        for (j = 0;  j < 3; j++)
            fprintf(dest, "%d %d %d ", red, green, blue);

        if (widthCounter == width)
        {
            fprintf(dest, "\n");
            widthCounter = 1;
        }

        else
            widthCounter++;
    }

    free(outputFilename);
    fclose(src);
    fclose(dest);
    return TRUE;
}
```

What am I doing wrong with reading the binary data? The height, width and depth are read flawlessly.

**EDIT:** After trying to play with the read data size I get some crazy results which I can't explain:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/qUyjUca.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzDYi.png]

Comment: You use `fscanf` for width and height but then a raw binary read for the colour variables. What if you replace the `fread` with `fscanf`?

Comment: @Jimbo, with what arguments? wouldn't it read it as pure binary?

Comment: `fscanf` will read ascii data from the input stream. `fread` will just read a blob of bytes. So I'm wondering, in you input file, is there ascii and binary data? I paranoia checked myself and wrote to a file with `fprintf` and then read back with `fscanf`. `fprintf` writes ascii and `fprintf` read it back correctly.

Comment: @Jimbo, yeah, PPM-P6 files header's are in ascii and data in binary, PPM-P3 are hold both header and data in ascii and that's the converting I'm trying to make

Comment: Ok. and the binary data starts on the first byte after the ascii data?  Is the P6 file generated on the same computer as yours?

Comment: @Jimbo, The P6 was converted using GIMP by my on my computer yes. In PPM documentation it says that: `In P6 magic number: A block of Height rows, in order from top to bottom. Each row consists of Width pixels, in order from left to right. Each pixel is a triplet of red, green, and blue samples, in that order. Each sample is represented in pure binary using one byte.`

Comment: if each sample is one byte, you will want to use `unsigned char` for the red/blue/green variables and do `fread(&var, 1, 1, src)` I would think. I reckon `sizeof(int)` is likely 4 (system dependent) so for each of red, green, and blue, you've been readin in 4 unsigned bytes and storing them in a signed integer...

Comment: When it says "each sample one byte" is that each pixel or each of the RGB components of each pixel is one byte?

Comment: Also if you're reading the three components using the three `freads` you won't need the inner `for( j...` loop I don't think.

Comment: @Jimbo As I understand it from Wikipedia and reading, a sample is a color so 1 Byte for Red, 1 Byte for Green and 1 Byte for Blue.

Comment: Are you sure you've gotten to the end of the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from our discussion in the comments thread for the question, I think the problem is in your reading of the binary data.

If each sample is one byte, you will want to use `unsigned char` for the red/blue/green variables and do `fread(&var, 1, 1, src)` I would think. I reckon `sizeof(int)` is likely 4 (system dependent) so for each of red, green, and blue, you've been reading in 4 unsigned bytes and storing them in a signed integer... this will lead to trouble.

Also, I don't think you need your inner loop `for(j = ...`

I would rewrite your inner loop as:

```
unsigned char red, green blue;
...
for (i = 0; i < width*height; i++)
{
    fread(&red, 1, 1, src); //<-- Note inner for(j... has been removed
    fread(&green, 1, 1, src);
    fread(&blue, 1, 1, src);

    fprintf(dest, "%u %u %u ", 
                  (unsigned int)red, 
                  (unsigned int)green, 
                  (unsigned int)blue);
    ...
```

Also, the spec I read at http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html indicates that the samples need not be one byte depending on the value of "... maximum color value (Maxval)...", which you seem to store in `depth`.

EDIT #1:
The reason I took out your inner j loop...

```
for (i = 0; i < width*height; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        fread(&red, sizeof(int), 1, src);
        fread(&green, sizeof(int), 1, src);
        fread(&blue, sizeof(int), 1, src);
    }
```

...was because this reads 9 bytes but only stores the value of the last 3 bytes read. This is because in the first loop iteration you read 3 bytes and store them, respectively, in the variables `red`, `green` and `blue`. Then the loop repeats and reads new data into these variables. Hence the last set of data is lost and so on...

Why putting this back in helped I don't know?! It implies that there are more bytes of pixel data available than I thought reading the standard. It says width*height pixels, at least that's how I read it, but with the `for(j...` loop you read 3*width*height.

Given what we've seen (see comments under question) it looks like without this loop you're not reading enough samples, but from the standard, I don't understand why (yet) :)

EDIT 2:
What if you try....

```
unsigned char red, green blue;    
...
for (i = 0; i < width*height; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        fread(&red, 1, 1, src);
        fread(&green, 1, 1, src);
        fread(&blue, 1, 1, src);

        fprintf(dest, "%u %u %u ", 
                      (unsigned int)red, 
                      (unsigned int)green, 
                      (unsigned int)blue);
        if (widthCounter == width)
        {
            fprintf(dest, "\n");
            widthCounter = 1;
        }
        else
            widthCounter++;

    }
}
```

Comment: For the following image :http://imgur.com/7t2RwHB
I get this result : http://imgur.com/yyXxLsL
argh

Comment: Urg... this is with the inner `for(j...` taken out and the rgb's as single bytes?

Comment: With or without the `for(j...)` I get the same result but yeah this is with RGBs treated as single bytes, Here's the updated code: http://pastebin.com/t4VvbnnC

Comment: Okay, I think we're moving in the right direction... is `depth` equal to `1`?

Comment: Ah just read that depth has a trailing "...single whitespace character (usually a newline)..."... do you discard this? Looks like you don't... probably want to check that out :)

Comment: I was just thinking of the same! Haha so we're on the right path for sure because if I change line 26 in the given code to `fscanf(src, "%d %d %d\n", &width, &height, &depth);` The output colors looks much closer to the ones they should: http://i.imgur.com/7BeJYLS.png but we're still missing something argh

Comment: lol kindof but the image is shafted! What is the value of `depth`??

Comment: `depth` gets `255` as should.

Comment: Woha, when I inserted the `for(j...` loop I get a much better result http://i.imgur.com/7yuPefY.png which is exactly what I expected to get but in a better quality. Now why the hell does there's such a massive quality loss?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Why do you need to read 3 rgb values then when "...Each pixel is a triplet of red, green, and blue samples,..." and there are width*height pixels. With your inner j loop, surely for each pixel you're reading 3 samples so 3*width*height "pixels"?

Comment: exactly, each pixel = (int red, int green, int blue) so I process 3*width*length samples for width*length pixels, don't i?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35844/discussion-between-jimbo-and-quaker)

Answer (score 1):

OK, the problem is in fread. Youre reading from the file

```
sizeof(int)
```

Depending on your compiler that value can be different (usually four bytes). In P6 format each color is stored in **one** byte (0 - 255). so when you're reading your values you're going out of bounds for each pixel.

try:

```
        fread(&red, sizeof(char), 1, src);
        fread(&green, sizeof(char), 1, src);
        fread(&blue, sizeof(char), 1, src);
```

and cast them later if you need. That should work.

**EDIT**: You should also delcare your rgb variables as **unsigned** ints

Heres some info about the P3/P6 file formats:
http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/ppm/